# How to get files from Google Cloud Storage bucket based on a regular expression?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get files from a google cloud storage bucket. The file name are something like `20180618_1400/SOMEID_20180618.jpg`, `20180618_1200/SOMEID_20180618.jpg`, `20180617_1400/SOMEOTHERID_20180617.jpg`, etc.

I want to get files based on `SOMEID`.
I tried using the following code with reg exp

`` bucket.getFiles({
            prefix: new RegExp(`[0-9_]*\/SOMEID_`),
        }, (err, files) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(files);
        }); ``

The expected result is files `20180618_1400/SOMEID_20180618.jpg` and `20180618_1200/SOMEID_20180618.jpg`. But the code returns all the files in the bucket.

I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The prefix has to be a string. This is a prefix, not a regex. I had a look to be sure [in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#getFiles) and it is, as expected, not possible.

The correct way to do that in GCS would be to structure your bucket in a way prefix as a string is usable. For example, having a directory for profile picture, another for pdf, ... And all files are named with your user id.

Example:

```
profiles/1245.jpg
profiles/7561.jpg
billing/1245-2018-10.pdf
billing/1245-2018-09.pdf
billing/7561-2018-10.pdf
...
```

If you cannot, you will have to get all items and then apply your regex on it. You have an example at the end of the `getFiles()` documentation

I think (it's been a while), you can use a regex using gsutils, but gsutils get all files and then apply the regex on the client side, so it won't be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same but was just wondering if its somehow possible.

Comment: Another way could be to execute getFiles just once, and to store paths in your DB. then you could apply your regex on your DB entries. But having a better GCS structure is to me the best solution.

Comment: I will change my GCS structure. Thanks