# Is there a way in firebase functions to delete storage files that match a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I can't find a way to delete all the files inside firebase storage that match a regular expression. I would like to use something like:

```
        const bucket = storage.bucket(functions.config().firebase.storageBucket);
        const filePath = 'images/*.png';
        const file = bucket.file(filePath);
        file.delete();
```

Or similar to be able to delete all files inside "images" with png extension.

I tried searching in Stackoverflow and in the samples repository without luck https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No.  In order to delete a file from Cloud Storage, you need to be able to construct a full path to that file.  There are no wildcards or regular expressions.

It's common to store the paths to files in a database in order to easily discover the names of files to delete by using some query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in Cloud Functions, you'll be using the Firebase Admin SDK. And the Cloud Storage functionality in there (`admin.storage()`) is a thin wrapper around the Cloud Storage SDK for Node.js. So if you search for [`cloud storage node.js path regular expression`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+storage+node.js+path+regular+expression&oq=cloud+storage+node.js+path+regular+expression&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.5849j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you'll get some relevant results.

- [How to get files from Google Cloud Storage bucket based on a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904187/how-to-get-files-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket-based-on-a-regular-expression), which indicates that prefix matching is quite possible with `bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'path/to/file' }...`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference mStorageRef = 
    storage.getReference().child("fotos_usuarios/"+id);
mStorageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
    for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
        if (item.getName().contains("SOME_WORD")){
            item.delete();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code! Would be great if you could add a few words of explanation how it works?